# How to count row by filtering the value using wildcard using DAX in powerbi?

Tags: filter, count, powerbi, dax, wildcard

I would like to count a row by having 2 filter. 1 filter is using wildcard.
I tried this, but the result is calculate all the row of category, looks the filter is not working

```
IF(CONTAINSSTRING('BI - 22','BI - 22'[Creator]="*Support*", COUNTAX('BI - 22', 'BI - 22'[Category]="Image and Data")
```

I am going to count the row of `'BI - 22'[Category]` when the value is equal to `Image and Data` and the `'BI - 22'[Creator]` is contain of this string `Support`.

I am newbie with powerbi, anyone can give me idea please.
I really appreciate, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
Count = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        'BI - 22',
        'BI - 22'[Category] = "Image and Data"
            && CONTAINSSTRING('BI - 22'[Creator], "Support")
    )
)
```

[image]